# MiKTeX setup fails with API error 126

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

During installation miktexsetup.exe fails with:

`Windows API error 126: The specified module could not be found.`

`Data: dllName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\MiKTeX209-core.dll"`

I found nothing on the web, what could solve this issue or where its from, only others having the question, no solution:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/mailman/message/12310714/
- http://miktex.10937.n7.nabble.com/Update-and-Install-Problem-API-Error-126-td1380.html

Comment: Such questions should be asked in the miktex issue tracker: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues

Comment: Posted question at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/134

Comment: You should add a few details, like your OS, which account (admin/user),  which installer (and its version) and which installation method (single/multi) you used. It is rather impolite to expect Christian to ask back for such basic info.

Comment: I didn't want to be impolite, but want to collect all neccessary information, therefore I raise the problem to discuss. To assume I have all this information and withhold it is also rather impolite, but I'll have the chance on Tuesday only to ask all of those myself.